# Why TypeError: document.getElementById() is null

Tags: javascript, document, getelementbyid

Why the following code generates `TypeError: document.getElementById("docPrint") is null`

```
var printwindow = window.open('', '', 'fullScreen=no');
printwindow.document.write('<iframe id="docPrint" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://localhost:8080/hiring/docs/Keneth _1340800082258/Keneth _resume_1340800082258.pdf"></iframe>');
printwindow.self.focus();
document.getElementById('docPrint').focus();
document.getElementById('docPrint').contentWindow.print();
```

Comment: Did you consider that the element of id `docPrint` does not exist? Because that is most likely what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix your calls to document.getElementById with 'printwindow':

```
printwindow.document.getElementById('docPrint').focus();
printwindow.document.getElementById('docPrint').contentWindow.print();
```

You might also want to keep a reference to the element in a variable, to avoid the boilerplate

```
var el = printwindow.document.getElementById('docPrint');
el.focus();
el.contentWindow.print();
```

Comment: I know all the answers are correct. I accept more understandable and simple one to me :). i have voted all.

Answer (score 3):

You are operating across two windows.

```
printwindow.document.write
document.getElementById
```

If you want to get the element you created in the popup then you have to call it's gEBI method.

```
printwindow.document.write
printwindow.document.getElementById
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepend`printwindow.` to each instance of `document.getElementById`:

```
printwindow.document.getElementById('docPrint').focus();
printwindow.document.getElementById('docPrint').contentWindow.print();
```